# How can I hide a javascript form inside a button?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a button which my users can use to confirm a choice.

So far, I have the button and a form. The form is a necessary part of this, since it will have information that the tool provider needs to connect the user's choice with the answer they give..

I need help hiding the selection box and having "TRUE" pre-selected, so once the user clicks on the button, the script will run and have the desired outcome. Ideally, "TRUE" should be the only option, since I'll have one option per button.

Here is my code:

```js
function onbeforesubmit()
{
return true;
}

    var error;
var form_lanuage = 'en';

function CheckInputs()
{
    var check_ok = true;
    error = "Wrong input!\n";
    if(check_ok == false)
        alert(error);
    return check_ok;
}

function SubmitIt(){
    if(CheckInputs() == true){
        if(window.onbeforesubmit)
        onbeforesubmit();
        document.ProfileForm.submit();
    }
}

function MailIt(){
    if(CheckInputs()){
        if((document.ProfileForm.subject.value=='') || (document.ProfileForm.msg.value==''))
        alert('Bitte f\u00fcr Sie die Nachrichtenfelder aus!');
        else
        document.ProfileForm.submit();
    }
}

function FieldWithName(frm, fieldname, numofield)
{
    if(!numofield)
        numofield = 0;
    field_count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; ++i)
    {
        if(frm.elements[i].name == fieldname)
        {
            if(field_count == numofield)
                return frm.elements[i];
            else
                field_count++;
        }
    }
}
function NumChecked(frm, fieldname)
{
    var count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < frm.elements.length; ++i)
    {
        if(frm.elements[i].name == fieldname && frm.elements[i].checked == true) ++count;
    }
    return count;
}
function NumSel(field)
{
    var count = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < field.length; ++i)
        if(field[i].selected == true) ++count;
    return count;
}

var multiFields = new Array();
var dateFields = new Array();
multiFields["interest[]"] = "interest"
multiFields["optin"] = "optin"
var arr_interest = new Array();
```

```css
input[type=text] {
    padding:5px; 
    border:2px solid #ccc; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
    border-color:#333;
}

input[type=button] {
    padding:15px 100px; 
    background:#000000; 
    border:0 none;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px; 
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'trade-gothic-next', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

input[type=button]:hover {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 0px 0px 1px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="preFill()">
<form name="ProfileForm" onsubmit="return CheckInputs();" action="https://test.com/u/register.php" method=get>
<input type=hidden name="CID" value="1234567890"><input type=hidden name="SID" value=""><input type=hidden name="UID" value="{{contact.uid}}"><input type=hidden name="f" value="444"><input type=hidden name="p" value="2"><input type=hidden name="a" value="r"><input type=hidden name="el" value=""><input type=hidden name="llid" value=""><input type=hidden name="c" value=""><input type=hidden name="counted" value=""><input type=hidden name="RID" value=""><input type=hidden name="mailnow" value="">repermission_optin:<select name="inp_7449" size=1><option value=""> </option><option value="1">TRUE</option><option value="2">FALSE</option></select><br>
<input aria-label='Register' tabindex='993' type=button onclick="javascript:SubmitIt()" name="submit1" value="Register"></form>
```

Comment: If "true" is pre-selected and the only option, why have a selection box at all? Why not make it a hidden input? Why must the form be inside the button? I don't think that's valid html, but you can't actually see a form, so you could have the form and hidden input and simply show the button to submit.

Comment: Where is `preFill()`?

Comment: If i understood correctly, You can just set `selected` attribute for the true option and hide the element using css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**remove the first option:** replace

```
<select name="inp_7449" size="1"><option value=""> </option><option value="1">TRUE</option><option value="2">FALSE</option></select>
```

with

```
<select name="inp_7449" size="1"><option value="1">TRUE</option><option value="2">FALSE</option></select>
```